# Populate Google Charts with ajax xml variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

How would I get my 'total' variable in my xmlParser function to display as a variable for Google Charts.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/X7qMV/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the AJAX call inside the drawChart function and populate the data from there.  Here's one way of doing it:

```
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: true,
        url: "https://test/computers",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function  (xml) {
            var size = $(xml).find("size");
            var total = (size.text());

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Work', total],
                ['Eat', 2],
                ['Commute', 2],
                ['Watch TV', 2],
                ['Sleep', 7]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: ''
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
}
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: awesome thank you, that works except when the variable is first, but i'll work it out.

Comment: Parse the XML as a number: `var total = new Number(size.text());`

Comment: Awesome!! I made one slight modification remove 'new' and just used Number. Thanks so much.